# column <> 1 returns False on NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables. `offers` and `offer_status`. I want to return rows from `offers` where the `offer_status` row is either missing or the `disabled` column in that table is 0.

Here is how I tried to do it:

```sql
SELECT offers.id,network,campid,name,url FROM offers
LEFT JOIN offer_status ON offers.id = offer_status.sql_id
AND offer_status.user_id='3'
WHERE country='US'

AND offer_status.disabled != '1'

ORDER BY epc DESC LIMIT 7
```

However, this does not work if the row in `offer_status` does not exist (and the JOIN fails). To me, it seems like it should still work though since offer_status.disabled is null.

This DOES work:

```sql
SELECT offers.id,network,campid,name,url FROM offers
LEFT JOIN offer_status ON offers.id = offer_status.sql_id
AND offer_status.user_id='3'
WHERE country='US'

AND (offer_status.disabled IS NULL OR offer_status.disabled=0)

ORDER BY epc DESC LIMIT 7
```

But to me this seems worse preformance-wise, and I am still disappointed my original thought didn't work.

Is the OR statement above the only way to do this? Is there a better method?

Comment: "But to me this seems worse preformance-wise,"  How exactly does it seem to be worse?  Did you measure before and after?  Or are you just going by feel?  You can't look at any performance issues without having quantitative measurements.

Comment: To make it more accurate you should do     `AND (offer_status.disabled IS NULL OR offer_status.disabled != 1)` in case of having other digits maybe.

Comment: @AndyLester - Unfortunately I am only going by feel. It's hard to measure before and after since the original one does not work :(

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL, but in Oracle, compare `NULL` to other values always return `NULL`, so `IS NULL` is necessary.

Comment: @Beko - thanks, although it is just a TINYINT (boolean) 1 or 0.

Comment: @hellohellosharp: Then how can you say that it feels worse?  You have no before to compare it to, so it can't possibly be worse.

Comment: Do any of the fields `network,campid,name,url` belong to `offer_status`?

Comment: @hellohellosharp Ok, then. It seems this is the only way since NULL cannot be compared with digits in MS SQL too. You can still measure those with performance tools of DB's.

Comment: @AndyLester - I don't **know**, I said it **seems**. Which is why I am asking the question: "Is the OR statement above the only way to do this? Is there a better method?"

Comment: @ConradFrix - thanks, but no, there aren't any errors being thrown.

Comment: 1. Adding another condition with OR will definitely slow query performance. 2. OP said what field is tinyint. Why to use '1' in query when dealing with integer?

Comment: @hellohellosharp I wasn't asking about errors. You have two tables in the FROM clause. Since you didn't use two part naming it unclear which table they belong to. If they don't belong to offer_status you can change the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL logic is a tristate logic with states TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN.  The WHERE clause selects rows where the condition evaluates to TRUE.

If you compare a NULL value with any non-null value, you get the third logic state, UNKNOWN (not FALSE as claimed in your title).  This is not the same as TRUE, so the rows where a condition evaluates to UNKNOWN are not selected.

You can use the explicit IS NULL test to check for nullness.

```
AND (offer_status.disabled != '1' OR offer_status.disabled IS NULL)
```

Note the extra parentheses for safety, clarity and accuracy.

If this is too much of a performance hit, enforce a NOT NULL constraint on the `offer_status.disabled` column, and then you do not have to fiddle around with the IS NULL test or OR'd conditions.  Generally, every column that possibly can be NOT NULL should be NOT NULL; it makes your database much easier to work with.

---

Note that if `offer_status.disabled` is NULL, then:

```sql
WHERE offer_status.disabled  = '1' -- evaluates to UNKNOWN and the row is not selected
WHERE offer_status.disabled != '1' -- evaluates to UNKNOWN and the row is not selected
```

This is the difference between the incorrect 'comparison with NULL returns FALSE' as claimed in the title and the actual behaviour of 'comparison with NULL returns UNKNOWN'.

Comment: hmm doesn't [null = '1'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5259) evaluate to null? What is this UNKNOWN you speak of?

Comment: UNKNOWN is the third truth value, but it is equivalent to NULL for all practical purposes.  The difference is that you can use an IS [NOT] TRUE, IS [NOT] FALSE or IS [NOT] UNKNOWN condition with slightly different semantics from IS [NOT] NULL.  Yes, [SQL](http://savage.net.au/SQL) is excruciatingly weird in this area.

Comment: Wow that is weird. I must have blocked it from my mind that UNKNOWN was a value for <truth_value> instead of null. I didn't see an <unknown predicate> only a <null predicate> so I'm not sure what you mean by the slightly different semantics. It also doesn't seem to be used in any DB I tested with.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing `NULL` (using `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>` etc) with another value yields `NULL`. And `NULL` is neither true, nor false. Secondly, in order to satisfy the `WHERE` clause, the condition must evaluate to true.

So, your second query is in fact the correct way to go.

For the sake of completeness, it is possible (but not recommended) to rewrite your query using functions such as [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), for example:

```sql
WHERE IFNULL(offer_status.disabled, 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [MySQL document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html):

> If one or both arguments are NULL, the result of the comparison is
>   NULL, except for the NULL-safe <=> equality comparison operator. For
>   NULL <=> NULL, the result is true.

So I think yes, `(disabled IS NULL OR disabled=0)` is necessary.